# How would I go about making a timer in python? (v3.4)

Tags: python

I want to make a quiz where when a question appears to the user  a preset timer willbegin before the question will display a message saying something along the lines of 'Sorry, too slow!'

Comment: Please provide some more context, and some source code fragment on what you already have.

Comment: Which OS?  Console or GUI?  If GUI, which one?

Comment: You cant import time and time.sleep(_seconds_) to show .

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [alarm](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.alarm).

This will work on POSIX systems, not too sure about Windows.